# boost::filesystem3::path::codecvt() undefined reference

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

Trying to use boost filesystem 3, but when I link I get the following undefined reference:

```
../myfile-g.o: In function `boost::filesystem3::path::codecvt()':
../boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp:377: undefined reference to
`boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()'
```

I grep'd everywhere in boost and there is no wchar_t_codecvt_facet()

Where is this defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are missing a linked library?  When I grep for it I get:

```
filesystem/v3/path.hpp:371  return *wchat_t_codecvt_facet();
filesystem/v3/path.hpp:462  static const codecvt_type *& wchar_t_codecvt_facet();
```

This is with boost 1.44 on macosx.  Since the function is defined in the header file it should be part of libboost_filesystem .  I'm not sure what compiler / linker you are using but the flag `-libboost_filesystem` will work if boost is properly on your path and you are using g++.

Comment: That's right, I keep thinking of Boost as a template only library but there are some parts that actually have a lib to link in! DUH, and this is one of them, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `-lboost_filesystem` for the newer versions of boost library.